# Get submatches of FIND OF REGEX statement

Tags: regex, find, abap

I would not only check a string for any occurrence of a substring using regex but also get the result ("45" in my example) of the found regex.

I tried:

```
 DO.
    FIND FIRST OCCURRENCE OF REGEX '[$][0-9]+[$]' IN 'safmaoigrevnwnfuwifhd$45$sdffge' 
        MATCH OFFSET lv_match_offset MATCH LENGTH lv_match_len 
        SUBMATCHES DATA(s1) DATA(s2) DATA(s3).
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
      " I expected s2 to contain the value between the "$"
      lv_match-value = s2.
      " remove found substring from annotation name for next loop
      lv_annotation_name = lv_annotation_name+lv_match_offset(lv_match_len).
    ELSE.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
```

s1, s2 and s3 are always initial but why? I thought that they would contain the value of the found regex, e.g. "$", "45", "$". What am I doing wrong? Is there a more elegant way than my approach?

Following Sandra's suggestion I changed the code to

```
FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX lv_index_regex IN lv_annotation_name RESULTS lt_matches.
```

Note that `FIND ALL ... MATCHES` does not exist, I assumed Sandra meant "RESULTS". `lt_matches` then contains the itab `submatches` but its always empty....

Comment: Yes I mean RESULTS. My post corrected. I explained in my answer why you don't get any "submatch" because you didn't define any subgroup.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not recognise the parentheses! Thanks, now it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word `SUBMATCHES` in the statement `FIND [FIRST OCCURRENCE OF] REGEX` is used to extract directly the [registered subgroups `(...)`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_syntax_operators.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SYNTAX_OPERATORS_6) (A.K.A. submatches) of the match into variables.

So, just put some parentheses around each of them:

```
FIND FIRST OCCURRENCE OF REGEX '([$])([0-9]+)([$])' 
    IN 'safmaoigrevnwnfuwifhd$45$sdffge' 
    MATCH OFFSET lv_match_offset 
    MATCH LENGTH lv_match_len 
    SUBMATCHES DATA(s1) DATA(s2) DATA(s3).
```

Note that your code will do an endless loop, but that's another question (it will be easier to find all matches at a time with `FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX ... RESULTS itab` and loop at the internal table, each line being one match, and each line also contains the list of the submatches).